# Mysql count total only if duplicates email OR phone

Tags: mysql, count, duplicates

I am trying to count total duplicate rows if email duplicates OR phone duplicates.

here is my table

```
email         phone  
john@a.com    2222222222
john@a.com    6666666666  
Stev@a.com    5656565656 
Mike@a.com    2222222222
```

the output should total rows has duplicate value phone or email

above duplicate, the count is **3**

Comment: This is iterative task. It needs in recursive CTE or iterative stored procedure.

Comment: If a row `Mike@a.com 333333333` added then the output will be 4? If there are 2 non-linked clusters with 3 and 4 rows each what must be the output?

Comment: @Akina if any column has multiple values add that row in the count

Answer (score 2):

Just find all duplicated emails and all duplicated phone numbers in the table and count the row if it contains a value from either;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Table1
WHERE email IN (SELECT email FROM Table1 GROUP BY email HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
   OR phone IN (SELECT phone FROM Table1 GROUP BY phone HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27c14b/1).

Comment: the database is very large if use subquery it will very slow

Comment: @Romil Do you have any indexes on the table? How long does the query take now?